# Using SSL certificate with Fleck Websockets

Tags: c#, websocket, wss

I get this error when pointing Fleck to my OpenSsl certificate, or cloudflare certificate

```
Failed to Authenticate System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)<---
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This generally means that the client is using an SSL protocol which is different than the server. You can specify the SSL protocol to support on the server by:

```
WebSocketServer ws = new WebSocketServer(wsUri)
{
EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
};
```